# Guaranteed HTTP forwarding frontend service (reliable cloud load balancer)

Tags: load-balancing, cloud, azure, rackspace-cloud, amazon-elb

My situation is fairly simple and, I guess, it's encountered fairly often. I have several projects which all look pretty much the same - a single project consists of:

1. Static content servers - there are a couple of decent CDN solutions that solve this problem
2. Frontend HTTP servers - which should get incoming requests, distribute them across backend servers, get the answers and post it back to users
3. Backend HTTP servers - scalable, properly distributed across the globe
4. Database servers / NoSQL servers / whatever stores the data

The problem here is (2) - frontend servers. We're using multiple technologies to provide fault-tolerance and load-balancing with frontends, namely:

- DNS round-robin & DNS zone switching - not really *that* good at load balancing, *very* slow to recover after a failure (i.e. switching of DNS zones takes at least 15-20 minutes in practice even with 1-minute TTL)
- BGP switching - fairly expensive, takes lots of organizational efforts (i.e. getting at least /23 block of IP address), not really practical to switch between more than 2 paths
- BGP anycasts - basically, also fairly expensive and complex
- Switching between servers in the same datacenter using VRRP/CARP at the router - most viable alternative, but not really fault-tolerant due to a single datacenter being SPoF

Come to think of it, I thought that there *must* be a ready-made SaaS solution for this problem. What I dream of for our next project is to make it this way:

1. Create backends, deploy them across the globe, have their IPs ready
2. Buy a domain name
3. Sign up for an external service that will:

   - Provide me with IP(s) that I will point my domain name to
   - Have a guaranteed web servers listening at these IP(s) all the time
   - Monitor my backends
   - Forward requests that it gets to a least loaded working backend (ideally, adjusting load balancing policy using some geographical / network latency principles)
   - Get response from a backend and send it back to the user

I did my homework and found out that there are several load balancing SaaS solutions available:

- [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) - but it's not really a frontend *forwarder*, but a frontend-serving-content (i.e. basically a CDN as a service)
- [Amazon Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) - seems to be what I was looking for, but it doesn't work with non EC2-hosted backends
- [Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/how-to-load-balance-virtual-machines/) seems to include some kind of "load balancer", but it also works only with Azure-hosted servers
- [RackSpace Cloud Load Balancers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/public/loadbalancers/) also seems to work only with RackSpace-hosted backends
- [Storm Cloud Load Balancer](http://www.stormondemand.com/servers/loadbalancer.html), again, seems to work only with Storm-hosted servers

I wonder if anything else exists that might make my dream deployment a reality? May be I'm wrong and such thing does not exist? Or I'm just searching for a wrong term and there's already another widely-accepted term for such a service?

Answer (score 1):

I'd google "global load balancing" or "global traffic management".

There's a few products out there from the usual players...

Akamai http://www.akamai.com/html/solutions/gtm.html

F5 http://www.f5.com/it-management/solutions/global-load-balancing/overview/

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion! From what I see now, both Akamai's and F5's solutions are not really what I'm looking for - they basically offer a DNS-based switching, which is slow and can be done manually without any organization hassle. I'm looking for a service to provide me a permanent IP that would forward traffic to/from my real servers in several datacenters.